# How can I get only protected and public constructors of a java class?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I can get all constructors(private, protected and public) using Java Reflection:

```
public Constructor<?>[] getDeclaredConstructors();
```

How can I get only protected and public constructors of a java class ?

Comment: Iterate through the returned array and check for modifiers. With Java 8 streams there will be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getConstructors()` returns public constructors. To get protected constructors you have to use `getDeclaredConstructors()` and then iterate over the array and check whether constructor is protected.

Here is the code sample:

```
for (Constructor c : clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
    if (Modifier.isProtected(c.getModifiers())) {
       // this constructor is protected
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I check whether constructor is protected or not?

Comment: Please see code sample that I added to my answer.][

Comment: please edit clazz.getConstructors() to clazz.getDeclaredConstructors() in for loop

Answer (score 1):

use `java.lang.reflect.Modifier;` for checking the modifiers(i.e: public, protected, public final, etc ):

```
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("ClassName");
    Constructor[] allConstructors = c.getDeclaredConstructors();
    for (Constructor m : allConstructors) {
        String modifier = Modifier.toString(m.getModifiers());
        System.out.println(modifier);
     }
```